# PostrgesSQL localhost authentication

Tags: postgresql

How do I configure postrgesSQL on my localhost machine to allow user **dziamid** to dump and restore any database with pg_dump and pg_restore?

I am using default configuration and server doesn't allow to use pg_dump:

```
Ident authentication failed for user "dziamid"
```

and both server versions 8.4 and 9.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured PostgreSQL with ident authentication, this involves that you need to be logged in the system as dziamid user, you can do this by switching the user :

```
su postgres
```

However if you want to digit password every time you need to change Postgre authentication type in the file pg_hba.conf from ident to md5 for example.

So for example (pg_hba.conf):

```
host    dziamid    all         192.168.1.1/24      md5
```

Then run :

```
pg_dump -U dziamid db_name > fileondisk.sql
```

Comment: I guess you meant `su postres`. Alos, I had to set the password for the user with `sudo passwrd postres` to be able to run `su postres`.

Comment: Yes, corrected.